# How can I accomplish this with Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following xml snippets:

```
<CreditCard 
   name="John Doe" 
   ccnum="1234123412341234" 
   ccv="239" 
   exp="03/13">
</CreditCard>


<CreditCard>
   <name>John Doe</name>
   <ccnum>1234123412341234</ccnum>
   <ccv>239</ccv>
   <exp>03/13</exp>
</CreditCard>
```

The above snippets are just two of many ways the xml can store the credit card data, so here is my problem, I need to scan through an xml string and find a 16 digit number which I have already done, but after that I need to determine where the security code is, the ccv in this case which I will assume will be a 3-4 digit number within the CreditCard element or something similar and then encrypt that.  My intial thought was to find the 16 digit number and then go back until I find the first beginning element and assume that that is the start of the credit card data and then go forward and search for a 3-4 digit number, but I am unsure how to go about doing that?

Let me assume I stick with Regex:

First I find the 13 - 16 digit number, so in the first example, I find:

1234123412341234, now I want to scan within there for a 3-4 digit number and that is where I am stuck.

Code:

```
//This encrypts 13-16 digit numbers, now I just need to encrypt the 3-4 digit security 
//code
foreach (Match cc in Regex.Matches(xml, @"\b\d{13,16}\b"))
 {

      Console.WriteLine(xml);
      Console.WriteLine(cc);
      xml = xml.Replace(cc.Value, "ENCRYPTED");
      Console.WriteLine(xml);

  }
```

Comment: Would suggest not using regex for parsing XML. Try an XML parser instead.

Comment: It is actually a string that contains xml.

Comment: May I know why you don't use an XML parser?

Comment: @Meysam - Because it is actually not XML, it is just a string that contains xml.

Comment: How many differen't combinations are there?

Comment: XML as a format is all string data. The problem is file symbols like line breaks and the varying ways you can put XML tags together are not good for parsing with regular expressions where you'd need to handle each case individually. An XML parser already takes care of the tokenizing portion for you which makes it a bit easier to use.

Comment: You're saying exactly the same thing. XML *is* a string, it doesn't matter what container it's in. The XmlDocument class can create an XML parser **from a string.** Use an XML parser, not Regex.

Comment: @Xaisoft As far as I know, the `XmlDocument` class in c# can load and parse XML from strings too.

Comment: So you are harvesting Credit card numbers and dont know how they are stored?

Comment: ok, good to know, but now my problem is that there can be 100s of ways to store the credit card data.

Comment: @Shiplu - Let me explain, the xml format for storing the credit card data is different for every implementation of a hotel property management interface.  There is no standard as some may store the security code as an attribute or element and some call it seriesCode while others may call it ccv or securitycode, etc.

Comment: @Xaisoft - In that case I suggest using an XML parser in conjunction with regex. Check each attribute and text node against something like `/^\d{3}$/` for CCV and `/^\d{16}$/` for credit card numbers.

Comment: Have you considered that not all credit card lengths are 16 characters?  For instance, AMEX is 15.

Comment: @DJQuimby - Yes, I just mentioned 16, but I am search for 13 - 16 digits.

Comment: @Michael - That is what I am thinking I need to do, but I am not sure how to combine the two, would you mind providing an answer with an example.

Comment: If there is 100s of way, how can it be regular? and how can you apply regular expression?

Comment: Is it safe to say all credit card numbers are either between > < or "" and the same for the CCV numbers? Are the other 3 digit numbers which might get a match within these constrants?

Comment: @Paul - It is safe to say that.  There may be other values that are 3-4 digits in length, but they would not be within the same element as the credit card number.

Comment: @Shiplu - The only regular thing about it is the assumption that the only 13-16 digit number is a credit card number.

Comment: @Paul - There certainly could be. Unfortunately parsing without context is really, really hard to do. I was going for a best effort and not necessarily 100% accuracy.

Comment: So why not find a match for a credit card number which is 13-16 (assuming these only match credit card details) and extract the whole line below. Then its easy to extract the 3-4 digit number From these matches  and you have what you need.

Comment: @Paul - Would you mind providing an answer with an example, I am a little confused.

Comment: @paul There's no guarantee that the CCV is on the next line. For instance, it could be attribute data like `<payment card="1234567812345678" ccv="123"/>`. You'd have to program in each different permutation that XML allows for formats.

Comment: @Michael - You are correct and there is no guarantee that the credit card number will be before or after the ccv num either.

Comment: Ok I assumed it would always be on the next line, scratch that then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this regular expression.

```
(\\d{13,16})[<\"'].*?(?=[>\"']\\d{3,4}[<\"'])[>\"'](\\d{3,4})[<\"'];
```

Note: I am **using regular expression as the XML schema is not regular**.

I wrote this assuming following rules.

1. Credit card number is a sequence digits of length between 13-16. Hence `\d{13,16}`
2. CCV number is a sequence digits of length 3-4. Hence `\d{3,4}`
3. CCV` should always appear after Credit Card number. And between these two there must be at least a single non-digit character. At least in most cases. Hence the whole pattern.

Let me know if any of my assumptions are wrong.

Sample Code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string data = @"<CreditCard> 
                   name=""John Doe"" 
                   ccnum=""1111123412341234"" 
                   ccv=""111"" 
                   exp=""03/13"">
                </CreditCard>


                <CreditCard>
                   <name>John Doe</name>
                   <ccnum>2222123412341234</ccnum>
                   <ccv>222</ccv>
                   <exp>03/13</exp>
                </CreditCard>

                <ResCreditCard 
                    resCreditCardRPH=""1"" 
                    cardCode=""11724"" 
                            cardType=""Credit"" 
                            cardNumber=""3333111111111111"" 
                            cardHolderName=""s"" 
                            expirationDate=""2015-03-31""
                            seriesCode=""333"" />";

        string pattern = "(\\d{13,16})[<\"'].*?(?=[>\"']\\d{3,4}[<\"'])[>\"'](\\d{3,4})[<\"']";
        Regex re = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);

        foreach (Match m in re.Matches(data))
            if (m.Success)
                Console.WriteLine(
                    "Credit Card Number={0}, CCV={1}",
                    m.Groups[1].Value,
                    m.Groups[2].Value
                 );

    }
}
```

Output

```
Credit Card Number=1111123412341234, CCV=111
Credit Card Number=2222123412341234, CCV=222
Credit Card Number=3333111111111111, CCV=333
```

Comment: For assumption 3, the CCV number may appear before the Credit Card Number.

Comment: Your regex matched the following `4111111111111111"
        cardHolderName="s" expirationDate="2015` in this snippet of xml: `<ResCreditCard resCreditCardRPH="1" cardCode="11724"
        cardType="Credit" cardNumber="4111111111111111"
        cardHolderName="s" expirationDate="2015-03-31"
        seriesCode="333" />`

Comment: I just need to match the cc number and the seriesCode.

Comment: When I try it here:  http://regexhero.net/tester/, it seems to have trouble with the leading / and the ending /is;

Comment: On http://rubular.com/, it tells me that ; is an invalid option and when I remove that, it says:  Undefined (?...) sequence.

Comment: Shiplu, did you test this in a particular tester.  I omitted the leading / and I had to omit the /is as well, but it only matches the following line:  `"4111111111111111" CardType="1" ExpireDate="0112"`.  I just want to match `4111111111111111` and `333`.  Also what if the data is not on a single line, do I omit the s.

Comment: Do you have sample code in .NET, I tried it but there are so many "'s that it is complaining about the regex pattern.

Comment: This works perfectly. I tried out the code against xml with attributes and elements and it is very nice.  Thank you so much for your patience on this.  If you have the time, would you mind breaking down the regex and explaining how each part works?  Also, are there any false positives that may occur?  Again, Thanks so much.

Comment: I noticed a couple things, it works with both elements and attributes, but if the seriesCode comes after the creditCardNumber, it does not match.

Comment: @Xaisoft you mean if *Assumption 3* false it doesn't match?

Comment: Yes, everything works fine expect if the seriesCode is before or does not exist.

Answer (score 6):

Not the pony again...

Is there a particular reason you can't just use XML? If there isn't, then you can just *use the XML*:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(myString);

foreach(XmlElement card in doc.GetElementsByTagName("CreditCard")) {
    // Use card.GetElementsByTagName("name")[0].InnerText, etc.
}
```

Comment: I like this solution, but my problem is that not all the XML which I do not control may not call it CreditCard, some may call it PaymentForm and some may store their stuff in attributes while others store it in elements.

Comment: @Xaisoft: You can get all these things with XML, just enumerate attributes and elements... hey, what exactly are you doing here?

Comment: I know I can get it, but the problem is I have no idea what they are called, it is different for every interface (property management system).

Comment: What I am doing is just assuming that a 16 digit number is a credit card number and then I want to scan the area and get a 3-4 digit security code and encrypt that

Comment: @Xaisoft: Take a look at the [`Attributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.attributes.aspx) and [`ChildNodes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.childnodes.aspx) properties. You can *enumerate* them. EDIT: And I kind of meant "are you doing something legal" because this sounds really suspicious.

Comment: @minitech - I am encrypting data so plain credit card data will not be stored in a db to be PCI compliant, so this is for security reasons and is legal.

Comment: @Xaisoft: Can you just encrypt the entire XML document and store that in your database?

Comment: No, because the PCI compliance only requires certain credit card data be encrypted and other data is used for debugging purposes.

Comment: @Xaisoft: Just because it doesn't require it all to be encrypted doesn't mean you can't do so... and I take it the other data is similarly "unextractable" then?

Comment: @minitech - Other data is used in case hotels complain that there was an issue with updating rates/inventory or processing a reservation for example.  If all data was encrypted, there would be no way for support to determine the issue.

Comment: @Xaisoft: How about... decrypt it?

Comment: if I encrypt the whole file and then decrypt it, the credit card data would be decryted. That should always be encrypted.

Comment: @minitech - While I understand your concern, I do not like the fact that you implied that I am doing something illegal.  In fact, I am doing the exact opposite in trying to figure out how to encrypt credit card data, not un-encrypt it.  I do not like the fact that you made an assumption that this is suspicious and illegal.

Comment: @Xaisoft: I'm not saying it is, just asking for verification. Plenty of people *do* illegal things, you know. Sorry if I offended you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the question.  I am assuming that at least you could separate each credit card as it would be enclosed in CreditCard tags.  If XML parser is not an option, should be easy to come up with an expression to match open and close tags.

After finding start / end of element, I would just search within for ccnum and grab the first set of continous digits after it, and also do the same for ccv.

Comment: The problem is that I used CreditCard as an example element, it could be called anything, it is implemented differently by the implementors who create these hotel interfaces.

Comment: I think given that the data is unpredictable, it really becomes like a data loss problem.  I think the only viable solution is writing an algorithm that has some hueristics to try and pair credit card and cvvs together.  Then, validating the cvv value against the credit card and then dealing with failures on a case-by-case basis.  But, I do not know how the cvv validation could work.